# Relationship (overlap, includes or exclude) between two multivariate normal distribution

Tags: algorithm, normal-distribution

Is there a way to compare two multivariate normal distribution models, given their means and covariance matrices, to see what relationship they have, if any? I am looking at topological relationships between the two distributions, such as, one overlaps other, or one includes other, etc.
I have checked various statistical measures - OVL, Hellingar distance, mahalanobis distance - but most of them are only for univariate normal distribution. I didn't find anything on multivariate distribution. If possible, an implementation of such algorithm would be very helpful.

Comment: I have also checked the Bhattacharyya distance, but could not find any implementation of the algorithm for multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Not sure what's worse: finding an old question that you need the answer to with a since-deleted solution, or finding one that never even got an answer.